# Execute a single non-Zend php file in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a website running on Zend and I have a single file that is written from somewhere else and does not follow the Zend framework.

The file merely imports content from another site so it is ok that it has no user interface and only needs to be run. Ideally I want to run it from the website front end (a single button click). I don't want to go through and re-write the code to load as a native Zend file.

How can I achieve this? Where should I place the file? The project is in `/var/www/projects/myproject`, inside `myproject` there is the usual application, cache, data, extra, htdocs, log, `nbproject` folders. Under the application folder, as standard Zend, there are models, modules, config, data folders.

Please let me know

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Can you provide more details about what the file does?

Comment: it just imports some content into the site; I modified it to use the site's database and tables. It isn't functionally challenging but I don't know Zend framework and it would be faster if I can just run the file from the frontend.